# List bullet size

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How to increase the size of a list bullet? I am using ""\u2023 ABC" and applying style with font size :16. However the bullet size does not scale and only the font size scales.

"\u2023"= unicode for the bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prasad, size of the bullet is also increasing with respect to the font size. But the probelm is the **size of the bullet is small compared to the text**. Please refer the screenshots I've taken in iPhone simulator with different font size

[image: smallest size 16]
[image: large medium with size 30]
[image: Largest with size 80]

The above in the above images, each of them has **font sizes 16, 30 and 80** respectively. You can see that the arrow size is also increasing with respect to the font size.

And here is a working solution for you.

[image: using 2 labels]

Here I've used two labels - one for the arrow and other for the city name having a font size 40 and 20 respectively, added them to the tableViewRow. You can change the font size as per your requirement

Here is my code

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < number_of_cities; i++ ){            
    var lblArrow = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text    : "\u2023",
        font    : {fontSize : 40},
        left    : '3%'
    });
    var lblValue   = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text    : cityList[i].name,
        font    : {fontSize : 20},
        left    : '10%'
    });

    tblData[i] = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    tblData[i].add(lblArrow);
    tblData[i].add(lblValue);
}
```

*Please note : I'm not sure that it's a best method, but it will resolve your issue*

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous variations of Unicode bullets and a quick visit to
[Geometric Shapes](https://web.archive.org/web/20220807230745/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) is always useful.  My personal favorite is "Black Circle" which, as with so much of Unicode, may be many things but a circle it is *not.*

`&#9679;` is a **nice fat bullet** — a bullet with *attitude*. In Hex it is `&#x25CF;` and parsed for the purposes of list styling written as `"\25AC"` in the `content` value of your `li:before` tag:

```
li:before {
    content: "\25AC";
```

etc.